# Creating a 2d array of custom objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

The goal of the following code is to create a 2d array such that

- Clip is a custom object
- a Bank is an array of (8) clips
- Banks is an array of (8) banks
- Each clip is accessible by banks[a][b], where a is an index in banks (a bank) and b is an index in clips (a clip)

In its current state it returns undefined, alas I am at a loss to explain why. Any suggestions about what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated

```
var banks = []

function Clip(a,b)

{
this.track = a
this.slot = b
}

function Bank(w)

{

for (var j, j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
    var clips = []
    var aClip = new Clip(w,j);
    //post(i)
    //post(aClip.length)
    clips[j] = aClip
}
//post();
return clips
}

function makeBanks()

{

for (var k, k = 0; k <= 7; k++) {
    var aBank = Bank(k);
    //post(i)
    //post (aClip.length)
    banks[k] = aBank
}
}

makeBanks();

console.log(banks[0][0])​
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your biggest mistake is here (inside `Bank`):

```
for (var j, j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
    var clips = []
    var aClip = new Clip(w,j);
    //post(i)
    //post(aClip.length)
    clips[j] = aClip
}
```

You're re-initializing `clips` each time through the loop, so that the only value that is retained is the last one (since the loop terminates before you get a chance to overwrite it again). To illustrate, this is what's returned from the first call to `Bank`:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 
     undefined, undefined, Clip { track=0, slot=7}]
```

Moving the declaration outside of the loop solves this basic problem:

```
var clips = [];
for (var j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
    var aClip = new Clip(w, j);
    clips[j] = aClip;
}
return clips;
```

### Additional Clean-up

Now that we've solved the basic problem, there's a lot more we could do to clean this up:

- Use semi-colons consistently
- Don't name functions with an initial uppercase letter unless you intend to use them as constructors
- Indent consistently
- Don't rely on global variables
- Declare and assign in one step (i.e. `var j, j = 0` should be `var j = 0`)

The result:

```
function Clip(a, b) {
    this.track = a;
    this.slot = b;
}

function makeBank(w) {
    var clips = [];
    for (var j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
        var aClip = new Clip(w, j);
        clips[j] = aClip;
    }
    return clips;
}

function makeBanks() {
    var banks = [];
    for (var k = 0; k <= 7; k++) {
        var aBank = makeBank(k);
        banks[k] = aBank;
    }
    return banks;
}

var banks = makeBanks();
console.log(banks[0][0]);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions, will endeavor to carry them out. In particular, you argue that I whould not use the global variable. How would I then make a banks array accessible to all functions?

Comment: @jamesson - Notice that `bank` is returned from `makeBanks`. The functional style encourages function parameters and return values over global variables. Simply pass that value along to any function that needs its.

Comment: reviewed the wiki on functional programming How in such a paradigm should we behave if we absolutely need a state? Example - I have a UI that behaves in 2 completely different manners based on whether a mousebutton is up or down.

Comment: @lwburk +1 for this pristine answer. Kudos to you for going above and beyond. Well done.

Comment: @jamesson - I'm not a purist. If you need state, then you need it. It didn't seem necessary in the contained example above, so I removed it. JavaScript supports multiple paradigms.